# Can't plot the result of a quadratic discriminant analysis using partimat in the klaR package in R

Tags: r, plot

I am working with the classic Pima indians and diabetes data set found 
[here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Pima+Indians+Diabetes).  I have read this data set in and called it Pima.

With the `klaR` package, I am attempting to use the `partimat` function to plot decision boundary, when I perform a quadratic discriminate analysis.

```
#install.packages("klaR")
library(klaR)
Pima[,9] <- as.factor(Pima[,9])
names(Pima) <- c("preggo", "glucose", "bp", "triceps", "serum", "BMI", "pedigree", "age", "class")
partimat(class ~ ., data=Pima, method="qda")
```

I get this error:

`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

I have searched on SO and elsewhere and haven't been able to find any reason for this.  My data set if far from gigantic, which I've read can cause problems.  I have attempted to manually give the pixel size to the function call.  I don't have any issues with the device that need to be addressed, that I am aware of.

Had anyone else had such a problem and possibly found a way to avoid this plotting issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `partimat()` tries to plot 28 individuals plots into the same figure. If the margins for these individual plots are too wide, they do not all fit into the same figure or plotting area. The easiest solution is to close the plot window (or a file) that you might currently have open, and then change the figure margins in the call to `partimat()`:

```
# Reading and preprocessing the data
Pima<-read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data", header=F, sep=",")
Pima[,9] <- as.factor(Pima[,9])
names(Pima) <- c("preggo", "glucose", "bp", "triceps", "serum", "BMI", "pedigree", "age", "class")

# Margins too wide, gives an error:
partimat(class ~ ., data=Pima, method="qda", mar=c(8,8,8,8))

# Margins more suitable:
# Open a new plot window
X11(width=15, height=15)
# Adjust the numbers for the option mar, if needed; see ?partimat and ?par 
# for more help on margins
partimat(class ~ ., data=Pima, method="qda", mar=c(5,4,2,2))
```

Comment: I'm amazed at what an excellent solution this is, and also amazed (as often happens) at the esoteric nature of the R programming language.  What is 'X11'??

Comment: `X11()` opens a new, empty plotting window. This works in Windows, and also in Linux in you have the X window system installed. In R ?X11 gives more details on this, also.